# Having cucumber automatically send an email with results

Tags: ruby, email, cucumber

So I'm setting up some cucumber features to automatically run every so often, and I would like to be able to send an email with the results if possible. Would it be possible to set up an ActionMailer to do (outside of a Rails app) or is there some other library that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

Use a CI server like Jenkins to execute your tests and mail the results.

http://sermoa.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/cucumber-running-headless-selenium-with-jenkins-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pony gem, which is the lightest weight way for sending mail from ruby that I've seen. Run your cucumber, and then used pony to send you an update. But honestly you could just use sendmail/etc from bash.

If you really want to automate your tests, I'd like at hudson (which has plugins for mail and just about anything else) or more ruby-specific tools like CI Joe or goldberg

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind use [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin to send email inside jenkins ?

And use cucumber related plugin to generate html result first, then send email with those static html pages

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't up to the CI server level yet. Our team is just getting comfortable with Cucumber, and I was looking for a short-term solution.